# flatMap issue converting from Angular 4 to Angular 9

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code in Angular 4 (all ok)

```
 public resolve(): Observable<GridViewDtcConfig> {

        const permissionResponse = this.flowsService.getPermissions();

        return permissionResponse.flatMap((permissions) => {
            const result = new GridViewDtcConfig();

            result.title = 'Outbound Flows';
            result.hideCompletedColumn = false;
            result.permissionResponse = permissions;
            result.successFlag = true;

            return Observable.of(result);
        });
    }
```

so far I have:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...... 
public resolve(): Observable<GridViewDtcConfig> {

    const permissionResponse = this.flowsService.getPermissions();

    return permissionResponse.pipe(flatMap((permissions) => {
      const result = new GridViewDtcConfig();

      result.title = 'Outbound Flows';
      result.hideCompletedColumn = false;
      result.permissionResponse = permissions;
      result.successFlag = true;

      return of(result);
    }));
  }
```

but it doesn't seem to like my use of flatMap. Can anyone advise on how I should be reconstructing the original code to conform to V9.

I receive the following error:

> const result: GridViewDtcConfig
>
> (TS) Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'. Type '{}' is missing the following
>   properties from type 'GridViewDtcConfig': title, hideCompletedColumn,
>   observableData, permissionResponse, successFlag

Comment: Try `mergeMap` instead of `flatMap`.

Comment: @AliF50 still gives the same issue.

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `of`, I would just use `map`.

Try this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; // use map instead and you won't need of
...... 
public resolve(): Observable<GridViewDtcConfig> {

    const permissionResponse = this.flowsService.getPermissions();

    return permissionResponse.pipe(map((permissions) => {
      const result = new GridViewDtcConfig();

      result.title = 'Outbound Flows';
      result.hideCompletedColumn = false;
      result.permissionResponse = permissions;
      result.successFlag = true;

      return result;
    }));
  }
```

Comment: interesting......Keeping flatMap, but changing my return as per your answer solved the issue. Thanks for persevering with me.